# Using word2vec to classify words in categories

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, gensim

**BACKGROUND**

I have vectors with some sample data and each vector has a category name (Places,Colors,Names).

```
['john','jay','dan','nathan','bob']  -> 'Names'
['yellow', 'red','green'] -> 'Colors'
['tokyo','bejing','washington','mumbai'] -> 'Places'
```

My objective is to train a model that take a new input string and predict which category it belongs to. For example if a new input is "purple" then I should be able to predict 'Colors' as the correct category. If the new input is "Calgary" it should predict 'Places' as the correct category.

**APPROACH**

I did some research and came across [Word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html). This library has a "similarity" and "mostsimilarity" function which i can use. So one brute force approach I thought of is the following:

1. Take new input.
2. Calculate it's similarity with each word in each vector and take an average.

So for instance for input "pink" I can calculate its similarity with words in vector "names" take a average and then do that for the other 2 vectors also. The vector that gives me the highest similarity average would be the correct vector for the input to belong to.

**ISSUE**

Given my limited knowledge in NLP and machine learning I am not sure if that is the best approach and hence I am looking for help and suggestions on better approaches to solve my problem. I am open to all suggestions and also please point out any mistakes I may have made as I am new to machine learning and NLP world.

Comment: use spacy's ner and you can also train the spacy model with your data.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul i will google that right now! thanks for feedback and if possible would love it if you can provide small demo, would love to see this

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you're looking for the simplest / fastest solution then I'd suggest you take the pre-trained word embeddings (Word2Vec or GloVe) and just build a simple query system on top of it. The vectors have been trained on a huge corpus and are likely to contain good enough approximation to your domain data.

Here's my solution below:

```
import numpy as np

# Category -> words
data = {
  'Names': ['john','jay','dan','nathan','bob'],
  'Colors': ['yellow', 'red','green'],
  'Places': ['tokyo','bejing','washington','mumbai'],
}
# Words -> category
categories = {word: key for key, words in data.items() for word in words}

# Load the whole embedding matrix
embeddings_index = {}
with open('glove.6B.100d.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    embed = np.array(values[1:], dtype=np.float32)
    embeddings_index[word] = embed
print('Loaded %s word vectors.' % len(embeddings_index))
# Embeddings for available words
data_embeddings = {key: value for key, value in embeddings_index.items() if key in categories.keys()}

# Processing the query
def process(query):
  query_embed = embeddings_index[query]
  scores = {}
  for word, embed in data_embeddings.items():
    category = categories[word]
    dist = query_embed.dot(embed)
    dist /= len(data[category])
    scores[category] = scores.get(category, 0) + dist
  return scores

# Testing
print(process('pink'))
print(process('frank'))
print(process('moscow'))
```

In order to run it, you'll have to download and unpack the pre-trained GloVe data from [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip) (careful, 800Mb!). Upon running, it should produce something like this:

```
{'Colors': 24.655489603678387, 'Names': 5.058711671829224, 'Places': 0.90213905274868011}
{'Colors': 6.8597321510314941, 'Names': 15.570847320556641, 'Places': 3.5302454829216003}
{'Colors': 8.2919375101725254, 'Names': 4.58830726146698, 'Places': 14.7840416431427}
```

... which looks pretty reasonable. And that's it! If you don't need such a big model, you can filter the words in `glove` according to their [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) score. Remember that the model size only depends on the data you have and words you might want to be able to query.

Comment: This is very interesting. So obviously the word embeddings have already been created. When i tried print(process('kobe')) it classified 'kobe' as a place even though 'kobe' is a name however when i added 'kobe' to the data dictionary as type name it classified kobe as a name . I am trying to understand what is happening under the hood. It gave the highest score to name (9.38) but the score for place category was pretty close (9.08).

Comment: Some terms are naturally on the border. Remember than embeddings are learned from the texts. E.g., `paris` is frequently used both as a city and a name, Paris Hilton. Same for Kobe: I know only one usage as a name, though very popular, but it's also as a place in Japan - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobe . This is a common problem in classification. As for the general understanding, see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46727571/712995 and further links it refers to

Comment: Also I found that when I did print(process('a2')) I got negative scores for all 3 categories. Then I added a new category called "Id" where i added values like a1,a2,b1,b2 . Then i did print(process('a2')) and print(process('c2')) and i got high score for "id" category in both cases. So the code above is it learning meaning of new values under the hood? Since i added a new category called Id it is somehow able to figure out that values like a1,b2,c3 are closely related.

Comment: Also would it make a difference if a value like "Kobe" occcours several times in Name category. Does this code take frequency of occurance in to consideration?

Comment: 1) Of course it would, but you'll have to change python dict to a list of tuples. It would be simpler to have a separate index of coefficients per different words, if you want to go this way. 2) Negative score is absolutely possible, no problem here. 3) This solution uses an *already trained* model. If you want to train it yourself, it's totally possible, but bare in mind the size of training data must very large to make a difference. Something comparable to the size of wikipedia.

Comment: I am confused because for a word like paris it makes sense that there is word embedding. For a term like "a1","a2" they are not english words so there are no embedding for them. So how is it exactly able to classify them in one category? I see the results i want but want to understand how it is happening

Comment: It knows a lot of words, because it was trained on an enormous text corpus. Which, apparently, has something about `a1`, `a2`, ... Describing GloVe in detail would need a lot of space, you can start here: https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/

Comment: I think it's a nice & elegant solution (+1); and terms on the border, such as 'kobe' (which I also knew as a place, and not a name), can be addressed with additional post-processing rules (e.g. when the difference between the two highest scores is below a threshold, return both etc)

Comment: @Maxim This looks good I tested it out just wondering what if i had a category with bi grams or tri grams. Lets say i have a bunch of addresses ('10 hacker road','123 washington street') etc. Would it be possible to use this approach still ?

Comment: @Dinero If I understand your question right, it's still possible, but will require a bit more work.

Comment: @Maxim would love it if you can add that approach to your answer or describe the approach

Comment: Maybe a little late to ask, but i need to know the meaning of the scores. Im doing this in a project and i dont know exactly how to explain this more than "The most points, the most accurate"

Answer (score 1):

Also, what its worth, [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) has a good and faster [implementation](https://github.com/spro/practical-pytorch/blob/master/glove-word-vectors/glove-word-vectors.ipynb) of Glove these days.