# Get trouble to load glove 840B 300d vector

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, word2vec

It seems the format is, for every line, the string is like 'word number number .....'. So it easy to split it.
But when I split them with the script below

```
import numpy as np
def loadGloveModel(gloveFile):
    print "Loading Glove Model"
    f = open(gloveFile,'r')
    model = {}
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split()
        word = splitLine[0]
        embedding = np.array([float(val) for val in splitLine[1:]])
        model[word] = embedding
    print "Done.",len(model)," words loaded!"
    return model
```

I load the glove 840B 300d.txt. but get error and I print the splitLine I got

```
['contact', 'name@domain.com', '0.016426', '0.13728', '0.18781', '0.75784', '0.44012', '0.096794' ... ]
```

or

```
['.', '.', '.', '.', '0.033459', '-0.085658', '0.27155', ...]
```

Please notice that this script works fine in glove.6b.*

Comment: Looks like a problem with the downloaded file. See this answer as an example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47758616/712995

Comment: Actually, I find all of the lines that will cause error, except for '.'*n , others are 
`['in', 'emailing', 'Email', 'email', 'At', 'at', 'by', 'to', 'in', 'or', '•', 'Contact','contact', 'is', 'on']`

Comment: Right and I don't see this line in my glove text file

Comment: Could you please tell me the size of your file in zip or just txt size?

Comment: `glove.6B.zip` is 862182613 bytes

Comment: Do you have glove.840B version? This script works fine in 6B version.

Answer (score 6):

The code works fine for files: glove.6B.*d.txt, glove.42B.*d.txt, but not glove.6B.300d.txt. This is because glove.6B.300d.txt contains spaces in a word. For example, it has a word like this: '. . .' and there are spaces between those dots. I solve this problem by changing this line:

```
splitLine = line.split()
```

into

```
splitLine = line.split(' ')
```

So you code must be like this:

```
import numpy as np
def loadGloveModel(gloveFile):
    print "Loading Glove Model"
    f = open(gloveFile,'r', encoding='utf8')
    model = {}
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split(' ')
        word = splitLine[0]
        embedding = np.asarray(splitLine[1:], dtype='float32')
        model[word] = embedding
    print "Done.",len(model)," words loaded!"
    return model
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following may help:

```py
def process_glove_line(line, dim):
    word = None
    embedding = None

    try:
        splitLine = line.split()
        word = " ".join(splitLine[:len(splitLine)-dim])
        embedding = np.array([float(val) for val in splitLine[-dim:]])
    except:
        print(line)

    return word, embedding

def load_glove_model(glove_filepath, dim):
    with open(glove_filepath, encoding="utf8" ) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        model = {}
        for line in content:
            word, embedding = process_glove_line(line, dim)
            if embedding is not None:
                model[word] = embedding
        return model

model= load_glove_model("glove.840B.300d.txt", 300)
```