# How to polish return and save to individual JSON/csv file?

Tags: python, json, csv

Below code is from [Using word2vec to classify words in categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666699/using-word2vec-to-classify-words-in-categories) and I need some help on input and return saveing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Category -> words
data = {
  'Names': ['john','jay','dan','nathan','bob'],
  'Colors': ['yellow', 'red','green', 'oragne', 'purple'],
  'Places': ['tokyo','bejing','washington','mumbai'],
}
# Words -> category
categories = {word: key for key, words in data.items() for word in words}

# Load the whole embedding matrix
embeddings_index = {}
with open('glove.6B.100d.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    embed = np.array(values[1:], dtype=np.float32)
    embeddings_index[word] = embed
print('Loaded %s word vectors.' % len(embeddings_index))
# Embeddings for available words
data_embeddings = {key: value for key, value in embeddings_index.items() if key in categories.keys()}

# Processing the query
def process(query):
  query_embed = embeddings_index[query]
  scores = {}
  for word, embed in data_embeddings.items():
    category = categories[word]
    dist = query_embed.dot(embed)
    dist /= len(data[category])
    scores[category] = scores.get(category, 0) + dist
  return scores

# Testing
print(process('jonny'))
print(process('green'))
print(process('park'))
```

And the return looks like:

```
Loaded 400000 word vectors.
{'Names': 7.965438079833984, 'Places': -0.3282392770051956, 'Colors': 1.803783965110779}
{'Names': 11.360316085815429, 'Places': 3.536876901984215, 'Colors': 21.82199630737305}
{'Names': 10.234728145599364, 'Places': 8.739515662193298, 'Colors': 10.761297225952148}
```

Below are the changes I want to make to this scrip but keep failing :( Please help.

Question 1: The order or category (data) is Names, Colors, and Places. But why does the retun has Name, Place, Color order instead? This is not important but was wondering why.

Question 2: Instead of using **print(process('jonny'))**, how can I input list of text from text file?

Question 3: Lets suppose name of input text file is TEST.txt. How can I save the return in TEST.JSON or TEST.csv file? Basically input and output as same name.

Thank yo so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Question 1: The order or category (data) is Names, Colors, and Places. But why does the return has Name, Place, Color order instead? This is not important but was wondering why.*

It's probably because of how the contents of 'glove.6B.100d.txt' are ordered/arranged.

---

> *Question 2: Instead of using `print(process('jonny'))`, how can I input list of text from text file? [Lets suppose name of input text file is TEST.txt.]*

Assuming 'TEST.txt' has an input in each line like

> ```
> jonny
> green
> park
> [input#4]
> [input#5]
> ```

Then you could read them into a list of strings to loop through and apply `process` to:

```py
with open('TEST.txt') as f: 
    inputList = f.read().splitlines()

# for inp in inputList: print(process(inp)) ## OR
outputList = [process(inp) for inp in inputList] 
for op in outputList: print(op)
```

---

> *Question 3: [...] How can I save the return in TEST.JSON or TEST.csv file? Basically input and output as same name.*

To save as CSV, you could use pandas [`.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)<sup>([view examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD6og.png))</sup>

```py
import pandas as pd
# pd.DataFrame(outputList, index=inputList).to_csv('TEST.csv') ## same as:
# pd.DataFrame([process(i) for i in inputList], index=inputList).to_csv('TEST.csv')
 
pd.DataFrame(
    [{'input': inp, **process(inp)} for inp in inputList]
).set_index('input').to_csv('TEST.csv')
```

and to save as JSON, you can use [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)<sup>(view examples: [op1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJCNL.png), [op2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORc6o.png))</sup>

```py
import json

with open('TEST.json', 'w') as f: 
    # json.dump([{'input':inp, 'output': process(inp)} for inp in inputList], f) ## op1
    json.dump({inp: process(inp) for inp in inputList}, f) #, indent=4) ## op2
```

---

##### Added EDIT:

> *Let's suppose I have a list of text files for this. Then how would I be able to process all the text files at once and save the return in the same file name? For example, if I use text1.txt, text2.txt, and text3.txt.....return will be text1.json, text2.json, and text3.json.*

```py
inpFiles = ['text1.txt', 'text2.txt', 'text3.txt']
# ifLen = len(ifLen)
for inpf in inpFiles: # for ifi, inpf in enumerate(inpFiles, 1):
    # print('', end=f'\r[{ifi} of {ifLen}] processing "{inpf}"...')
    with open(inpf) as f: inputList = f.read().splitlines()
    with open(f'{inpf[:-4]}.json', 'w') as f:   
        json.dump({inp: process(inp) for inp in inputList}, f, indent=4)
```

[Using *`f'{inpf[:-4]}.json'`* assumes all file names in *`inpFiles`* end with '.txt']

Comment: Wow life saver! thank you so much! bless you, brother. Everything works like a dream!

Comment: Sorry to ask more, but one last thing. Let's suppose I have a list of text files for this. Then how would I be able to process all the text files at once and save the return in the same file name? For example, if I use text1.txt, text2.txt, and text3.txt.....return will be  text1.json, text2.json, and text3.json. @Driftr95

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, @Driftr95

The below code allows to input of multiple text files and then saving the return in individual json files.

```
inpFiles = ['text1.txt', 'text2.txt', 'text3.txt']
# ifLen = len(ifLen)
for inpf in inpFiles: # for ifi, inpf in enumerate(inpFiles, 1):
    # print('', end=f'\r[{ifi} of {ifLen}] processing "{inpf}"...')
    with open(inpf) as f: inputList = f.read().splitlines()
    with open(f'{inpf[:-4]}.json', 'w') as f:   
        json.dump({inp: process(inp) for inp in inputList}, f, indent=4)
```