# How to match words in a dump to a particular subject

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, gensim

I have 10 words in a text file . - Eg

1. Sarat Saratha Sarathi Saratogue Saravana Saraya Sarbamouli Sarcasm
   Sarcastic Sarcinae Sarcocystes Sarcodina Sarcoidoins Sarcoma
   Sarcophaga Sarcophagi Sarcoplasmic Sarcotesta

I would like to auto tag it to 3 subjects - History , Polity  , Science . Some words can fall into 2 categories , some may not fall in all there . Thats fine . But , how do I take it forward .

What I have tried till now - I tried gensim-data . But , even for a very small sample size it takes huge time to run . I planned to use Spacy and NLTK . But , unable to use them effeciently . Looking for directional input and any rudimentary program which I can build upon .

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666699/using-word2vec-to-classify-words-in-categories) might be helpful.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called 'classification' – specifically, classifying items (that are single words) into 3 classes. `gensim-data` is just some useful demo/pretrained datasets, not any sort of classifier on its own, so saying "I tried gensim-data" doesn't really hint what you tried, without more details/code. If your real task is to just assign those 10 words, you should do it manually with your own research. If your real task is to do his at some larger scale, then it'd be helpful to know the real scale of data/classes involved, to know how a system might be trained.

Comment: Hi @gojomo . So , this is what I am trying to do . 

I have question paper(s) which has English and Tamil MCQ s in it . I am extracting key words from each of the question and storing them in a text file . Then , I am trying to see to which of subject a key word can be tagged to . 

TO make things eassier , I said its a 10 word and 3 subjects . Actually its spread across 15 chunks of txt file and the subjects may be around 20-25 .

Comment: Hi @Ro.oT. Thanks for the pointer . But , do the models take long (really long) time to give simple outputs ?

Comment: Thanks. What does 'MCQ' mean? Why do you want to classify the keywords you've chosen (by some unspecified process), instead of the whole questions? Do you have a fixed list of subjects, or are you trying to discover them automatically? Do you have any 'gold standard' examples with correct subjects, or some other way to determine what the 'right' or 'desired' classifications are?

Comment: @gojomo . 
1.MCQ - Multiple Choice Question 

2.Its because , I am taking them from a OCRed PDF and storing it as a search term . IN that case , I get words and not questions 

3.I have close to 15 different subjects are they are fixed . But , I may increase them . Even in that case they are fixed . 

4.I dont have any standard and not look for accurate answers , but approximations are fine .

Comment: Doesn't the OCR read in the whole question from the PDF showing the questions? Even if at first you're just ad-hoc eyeballing the results, one way or another, you have some defacto way of determining whether results are 'good enough', or 'better' than some alternative – and to actually choose a good approach, & improve it, you should try to turn that into some sort of repeatable objective evaluation as soon as possible. (For example, starting to collect your own determinations of what subject is correct, so that when you change/tune methods, you can tell if it starts doing better or worse.)